# Floating point issue always (n+1) in php

Tags: php, match

My requirement is round no +1.

As i have:

Target output will be:

```
$a = round(4.9); (output will be 5)
$b = round(4.5);  (output will be 5)
$c = round(4.4999); (output will be 5)
```

Comment: you mean 6 as a result of 4.999???

Comment: no no if i print $a it's give r8 answer 5 , $b also gives 5 but $c gives 4 i should return 5 in every case

Comment: so your answer is ready take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

> ```
> float ceil ( float $value )
> ```
>
> Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up `value` if necessary.

Also take note of its opposite, [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) not `round()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) for this. This returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value.

```
<?php
$a = ceil(4.9);     //5
$b = ceil(4.5);     //5
$c = ceil(4.4999);  //5
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get next height integer you need use [ceil](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_ceil.asp) function of PHP.

So use `ceil` at `round`:

```
$a = ceil(4.9); (output will be 5)
$b = ceil(4.5);  (output will be 5)
$c = ceil(4.4999); (output will be 5)
```